# Adding spring-boot-starter-parent removes javax.validation.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When i add to the top pom this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

These imports got broke from it:

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
```

I don't see anything in `javax.validation.*`

When i remove this parent - everything is back to normal.

I use JDK 8 and plan to advance for JDK 11 in the future.

Comment: What JDK version do you use ?

Comment: I use JDK 8 and plan to advance for JDK 11 in the future.

Comment: I would guess that, due to its dependency management, adding `spring-boot-starter-parent` has changed the version of the Validation API used by your project. This will have caused Maven to download a new jar file and I suspect that it has corrupted it. Try clearing out Maven's cache and rebuilding your application.

Answer (score 0):

Its happend because "org.springframework.boot" already contains "javax.validation" jars

So, if you want to use the previous version or external maven entry of "javax.validation" jar then exclude that dependency from spring-boot-starter-parent maven.

example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: when using it like parent - elements like `type` or `exclusions` are not allowed. I am trying to do this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-parent-pom

Comment: instead of inheriting parent dependency you can add the dependency separately.
So, remove your parent tag and add 'spring-boot-starter-parent' dependency with exclusion.

Comment: But if i have a lot of poms (100+ with their hierarchy) do you think it works the same as specifing the `parent` in the root pom?

Comment: If you are inheriting 100+ dependencies from parent then don't do that. It will will introduce more dependency issues.

Use 'mvn dependency:tree' command and find the parent dependency which have 'javax.validation' dependency and exclude from that.
I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot already contains javax.validation, so you have to remove the associated dependency from your pom.xml.

Comment: If i comment all `javax.validation` depedencies still these imports are not recognized.

Comment: It is weird. Did you "clean install" everything after that with Maven ?